# Who is the most powerful god according to Buddhism?

Tags: god

In Buddhism, gods are acknowledged to exist. So, according to Buddhism, who is considered the most powerful god?

Comment: May I know what is your definition of powerful? Wise? Omnipotent? Omniscient?

Comment: There are like ~330 million gods (excluding Brahmas) and their king is considered very powerful. Which is the `Shakra`.

Comment: {In Buddhism, gods are acknowledged to exist. }, yes. But not some strange beings. Just some living forms of consciousness with grater wealth of happiness.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a being called the Mahabrahma or Great Brahma.

> "There are, bhikkhus, some recluses and brahmins who are eternalists in regard to some things and non-eternalists in regard to
> other things, and who on four grounds proclaim the self and the world
> to be partly eternal and partly non-eternal. And owing to what, with
> reference to what, do these honorable recluses and brahmins proclaim
> their views?
>
> "There comes a time, bhikkhus, when after the lapse of a long period this world contracts (disintegrates). While the world is
> contracting, beings for the most part are reborn in the Ābhassara
> Brahma-world.<sup>7</sup> There they dwell, mind-made, feeding on rapture,
> self-luminous, moving through the air, abiding in glory. And they
> continue thus for a long, long period of time.
>
> "But sooner or later, bhikkhus, after the lapse of a long period, there comes a time when this world begins to expand once again. While
> the world is expanding, an empty palace of Brahmā appears. Then a
> certain being, due to the exhaustion of his life-span or the
> exhaustion of his merit, passes away from the Ābhassara plane and
> re-arises in the empty palace of Brahmā. There he dwells, mind made,
> feeding on rapture, self-luminous, moving through the air, abiding in
> glory. And he continues thus for a long, long period of time.
>
> "Then, as a result of dwelling there all alone for so long a time, there arises in him dissatisfaction and agitation, (and he yearns):
> 'Oh, that other beings might come to this place!' Just at that moment,
> due to the exhaustion of their life-span or the exhaustion of their
> merit, certain other beings pass away from the Ābhassara plane and
> re-arise in the palace of Brahmā, in companionship with him. There
> they dwell, mind-made, feeding on rapture, self-luminous, moving
> through the air, abiding in glory. And they continue thus for a long,
> long period of time.
>
> "Thereupon the being who re-arose there first thinks to himself: 'I am Brahmā, the Great Brahmā, the Vanquisher, the Unvanquished, the
> Universal Seer, the Wielder of Power, the Lord, the Maker and Creator,
> the Supreme Being, the Ordainer, the Almighty, the Father of all that
> are and are to be. And these beings have been created by me. What is
> the reason? Because first I made the wish: "Oh, that other beings
> might come to this place!" And after I made this resolution, now these
> beings have come.'
>
> "And the beings who re-arose there after him also think: 'This must be
> Brahmā, the Great Brahmā, the Vanquisher, the Unvanquished, the
> Universal Seer, the Wielder of Power, the Lord, the Maker and Creator,
> the Supreme Being, the Ordainer, the Almighty, the Father of all that
> are and are to be. And we have been created by him. What is the
> reason? Because we see that he was here first, and we appeared here
> after him.'
>
> "Herein, bhikkhus, the being who re-arose there first possesses longer life, greater beauty, and greater authority than the beings who
> re-arose there after him.
>
> "Now, bhikkhus, this comes to pass, that a certain being, after passing away from that plane, takes rebirth in this world. Having come
> to this world, he goes forth from home to homelessness. When he has
> gone forth, by means of ardor, endeavor, application, diligence, and
> right reflection, he attains to such a degree of mental concentration
> that with his mind thus concentrated he recollects his immediately
> preceding life, but none previous to that. He speaks thus: 'We were
> created by him, by Brahmā, the Great Brahmā, the Vanquisher, the
> Unvanquished, the Universal Seer, the Wielder of Power, the Lord, the
> Maker and Creator, the Supreme Being, the Ordainer, the Almighty, the
> Father of all that are and are to be. He is permanent, stable,
> eternal, not subject to change, and he will remain the same just like
> eternity itself. But we, who have been created by him and have come to
> this world, are impermanent, unstable, short-lived, doomed to perish.'
>
> "This, bhikkhus, is the first case.
> [DN 1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.01.0.bodh.html)

> Note:
> 7. The "world of streaming radiance," the sixth of the fifteen
> planes in the fine-material world (rūpaloka), the lowest order to be
> exempt from the onset of world destruction. The Brahma-world mentioned
> later is destroyed by the conflagration but reappears at an early
> stage.

Comment: It's debatable what he meant by gods. Is he including Brahmas or not?

Answer (score -1):

All Gods are not worth calling Self because becoming God leads to rebirth , ageing , death and whole mass of suffering. There are Gods with different responsibilities. There is no one God.